# How do I create c# Model class to generate particular XML

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm creating a WCF service. I want to create a model class which accepts XML request as follows.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1r3="http://testsite.net/v1r3">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1r3:registerApp>
         <request>
            <header channel="?" componentId="?" lang="?" operatorId="?" timestamp="?" timeout="?" subver="?">
               <msgId>?</msgId>
            </header>
            <issuer issId="?" appId="?"/>
            <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
            <!--Optional:-->
            <msisdnDigest>?</msisdnDigest>
            <app>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ibanEncr serialNumer="?">cid:1412419884089</ibanEncr>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <appEncrData serialNumer="?">cid:333152353834</appEncrData>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <appLabel>?</appLabel>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <appType>?</appType>
            </app>
            <autoActivateFlg>true</autoActivateFlg>
         </request>
      </v1r3:registerApp>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

**Things I've tried.**

1. [XML2Csharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Generated a class as below which does not generate the same XML.

```
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="header")]
    public class Header {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="msgId")]
        public string MsgId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="channel")]
        public string Channel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="componentId")]
        public string ComponentId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="operatorId")]
        public string OperatorId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="timestamp")]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="timeout")]
        public string Timeout { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="subver")]
        public string Subver { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="issuer")]
    public class Issuer {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="issId")]
        public string IssId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="appId")]
        public string AppId { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="ibanEncr")]
    public class IbanEncr {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="serialNumer")]
        public string SerialNumer { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="appEncrData")]
    public class AppEncrData {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="serialNumer")]
        public string SerialNumer { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="app")]
    public class App {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="ibanEncr")]
        public IbanEncr IbanEncr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="appEncrData")]
        public AppEncrData AppEncrData { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="appLabel")]
        public string AppLabel { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="appType")]
        public string AppType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="request")]
    public class Request {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="issuer")]
        public Issuer Issuer { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="msisdnDigest")]
        public string MsisdnDigest { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="app")]
        public App App { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="autoActivateFlg")]
        public string AutoActivateFlg { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="registerApp", Namespace="http://testsite.net/v1r3")]
    public class RegisterApp {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="request")]
        public Request Request { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="registerApp", Namespace="http://testsite.net/v1r3")]
        public RegisterApp RegisterApp { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Header", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public string Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="soapenv", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soapenv { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="v1r3", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string V1r3 { get; set; }
    }
```

2. XSD.exe
3. SvcUtil.exe
4. Visual Studio Paste Special (Paste XML as Classes)

The generated model class creates a different XML as below.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IRegister/RegisterApp</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <RegisterApp xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <model xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.test" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:Body>
          <d4p1:RegisterApp>
            <d4p1:Request>
              <d4p1:App>
                <d4p1:AppEncrData i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:AppLabel i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:AppType i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:IbanEncr i:nil="true" />
              </d4p1:App>
              <d4p1:AutoActivateFlg i:nil="true" />
              <d4p1:Header>
                <d4p1:Channel i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:ComponentId i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:Lang i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:MsgId i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:OperatorId i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:Subver i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:Timeout i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:Timestamp i:nil="true" />
              </d4p1:Header>
              <d4p1:Issuer>
                <d4p1:AppId i:nil="true" />
                <d4p1:IssId i:nil="true" />
              </d4p1:Issuer>
              <d4p1:MsisdnDigest i:nil="true" />
            </d4p1:Request>
          </d4p1:RegisterApp>
        </d4p1:Body>
        <d4p1:Header i:nil="true" />
        <d4p1:Soapenv i:nil="true" />
        <d4p1:V1r3 i:nil="true" />
      </model>
    </RegisterApp>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

which is not the same as the first one.

I've created a Simple WCF service as below where I want to accept the first XML to bind to that model.

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IRegister
    {
        [OperationContract]
        RegisterAppResponse RegisterApp(Xml2CSharp.Envelope model);

    }
```

Any way to generate a model class which will accept xml requests as above?

Comment: How have you configured your service? Are you actually using a SOAP serializer? There's a lot you've left out of your question, including a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I've updated the question according to your comment. I haven't used SOAP serializer.

Comment: _"I haven't used SOAP serializer"_ -- given that the XML you intend to produce appears to be for SOAP serialization, perhaps you should consider doing that.

Comment: So I cannot bind an Incoming XML to the model as a parameter without serialization?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that last question. Serialization is _exactly_ the act of taking some form of streamed (serial) data, like XML, and converting it to or from an in-memory code object. Which is what your whole question appears to be about. "Bind XML to the model" could, I suppose, mean instead to just copy the text (as a `string` object) to a _single_ property of a model object, leaving you with just the plain XML in code, which you'd still then have to interpret somehow. But it didn't sound like that's what you wanted.